# No render in Cycles but the object is rendered in Eevee,

Tags: cycles-render-engine

Good render in the vp with Eevee, but it disappears in the vp in Cycles. What am I doing wrong? It's probably super easy but can't find solution to this. this are many meshes with hair particles

[image: in Cycles]

https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dMKe10s0/

Comment: All I can see from the picture is that the object is hidden in viewport view. Any chance you hid it in rendered view as well? Check by going to  Object properties > visibility  and make sure  "show in viewport" and "show in renders" are checked.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=dMKe10s0" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/dMKe10s0/)

Comment: these are many objects and are not hidden

Comment: Too much particle for cycle to build and render the scene, please try other approach then using hair particle system directly. Particle is considered as the most complicated part of CG for now. Blender can produce some effect but you need to know what these setting is doing. Or you will soon encounter the performance issue

Comment: Thank You HikariTW. It's my first attempt at hair particles, so didn't know how heavy is on the render. I will dig further into it.